# assert self.ctx is not None AssertionError - TheBloke/Manticore-13B-GGML

Tags: python, huggingface

So i found this repo, and i've been trying to make it work in google colab.
https://github.com/ecliipt/personal-assistant/tree/main

i am using the Manticore-13B.ggmlv2.q5_1.bin model, i've already tried using ggmlv3 but got the same error.
i'm using torch 2.0.1 on cpu and i also changed some things from the original repo's code.

here's the error that i get when running retrievalQA.py (py 3.10.12):

```
Loading the Manticore-13B.ggmlv2.q5_1.bin model...
llama.cpp: loading model from models/manticore-13b/Manticore-13B.ggmlv2.q5_1.bin
error loading model: unknown (magic, version) combination: 4f44213c, 50595443; is this really a GGML file?
llama_init_from_file: failed to load model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/personal-assistant/retrievalQA.py", line 61, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/personal-assistant/retrievalQA.py", line 40, in main
    llm = load_local_model(model_path, provider='llamacpp')   
  File "/content/personal-assistant/retrievalQA.py", line 28, in load_local_model
    llm = LlamaLLM(model_path, n_gpu_layers=n_gpu_layers, 
  File "/content/personal-assistant/pa/llm/llamacpp.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.model = Llama(model_path=model_path, 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/llama_cpp/llama.py", line 162, in __init__
    assert self.ctx is not None
AssertionError
```

but if i try with older versions of llama-cpp-python like 0.1.25 (running retrievalQA.py):

```
TypeError: Llama.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_gpu_layers'
```

i'm also always running into other error when i run inject.py:

```
load INSTRUCTOR_Transformer
max_seq_length  512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/personal-assistant/inject.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/personal-assistant/inject.py", line 59, in main
    db = Chroma.from_documents(texts, instructor_embeddings, 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 435, in from_documents
    return cls.from_texts(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 403, in from_texts
    chroma_collection.add_texts(texts=texts, metadatas=metadatas, ids=ids)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 148, in add_texts
    embeddings = self._embedding_function.embed_documents(list(texts))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/embeddings/huggingface.py", line 158, in embed_documents
    embeddings = self.client.encode(instruction_pairs, **self.encode_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/InstructorEmbedding/instructor.py", line 524, in encode
    if isinstance(sentences[0],list):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

i've been searching but i could not find a solution until now. llamaCpp and torch versions, tried with ggmlv2 and 3, both give me those errors.

and thats about it, thanks :)